# How browser detect when OS is going to hibernate/sleep

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, event-listener

I have to execute a function before the OS hibernate/sleep to gracefully close webrtc connection. Is there an event listener or a certain way to detect that in browser?

I have tried with "beforeunload" but it doesn't catch it.

Answer (score 3):

There is an draft freeze event

https://wicg.github.io/page-lifecycle/spec.html

but is not widely or reliably supported at moment of answering

https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_document_freeze_event

If you want an implementation of the freeze event you can find it at https://whatwebcando.today/freeze-resume.html

> ### API glimpse
>
> ```
> document.addEventListener('freeze')
> ```
>
> An event fired when the page has been frozen and unloaded by the operating system.
>
> ```
> document.addEventListener('resume')
> ```
>
> An event fired when the page has been resumed after being frozen by the operating system.
>
> ```
>  document.wasDiscarded
> ```
>
> A boolean flag indicating whether the current load has happened after the web application has been previously discarded.

Relevant code snippet from that page.

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');

if ('wasDiscarded' in document) {
  document.getElementById('wasDiscarded').innerText = document.wasDiscarded.toString();
}

function getState() {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    return 'hidden';
  }
  if (document.hasFocus()) {
    return 'focused';
  }
  return 'not focused';
};

var state = getState();

function logStateChange(nextState) {
  var prevState = state;
  if (nextState !== prevState) {
    var timeBadge = new Date().toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
    var newLog = document.createElement('p');
    newLog.innerHTML = '' + timeBadge + ' State changed from ' + prevState + ' to ' + nextState + '.';
    target.appendChild(newLog);
    state = nextState;
  }
};

function onPageStateChange() {
  logStateChange(getState())
}

['pageshow', 'focus', 'blur', 'visibilitychange', 'resume'].forEach(function (type) {
  window.addEventListener(type, onPageStateChange, {capture: true});
});

function onFreeze() {
  logStateChange('frozen');
}

window.addEventListener('freeze', onFreeze, {capture: true});

function onPageHide(event) {
  if (event.persisted) {
    // If the event's persisted property is `true` the page is about
    // to enter the page navigation cache, which is also in the frozen state.
    logStateChange('frozen');
  } else {
    // If the event's persisted property is not `true` the page is about to be unloaded.
    logStateChange('terminated');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('pagehide', onPageHide, {capture: true});
```

```html
<p>Was current page load initiated from a discarded state? 
  <b id="wasDiscarded">unknown</b>.</p>
  <p>Change the browser tab state to observe the changes log.</p>
<div id="target"></div>
<p><small>Based on the demo from <a href="https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Google Developers</a>.</small></p>
```

Comment: This is quite helpful but doesn't solve the problem completely. It triggers when the OS is going to hibernate/sleep but also when you change tab. I only need the cases where the OS goes to sleep.

Comment: @user1591482 It's the best you're going to get though. Browsers are very wary about giving access to the bare bones to random javascript